# Parent PID value saved for child process, but not grandchildren process in C program

Tags: c, linux

This is my first time writing in C, and the assignment is to create 10 processes = 1 parent, 3 children, 6 grandchildren. The children save the parent PID, and the grandchildren save their parent PID but not grandparent PID (which is the original parent PID).

```
int main() {
    pid_t c1_pid, g1_pid, g2_pid;
    (c1_pid = fork());

    if (c1_pid == 0) {
        (g1_pid = fork()) && (g2_pid = fork());
        if (g1_pid == 0) {
            sleep(1);
            printf("First Grandchild. Parent's PID is %d. Grandparent's PID is %d.\n",
                getppid(), getpid());
            exit(0);
        }
        else if (g2_pid == 0) {
            printf("Second Grandchild. Parent's PID is %d. Grandparent's PID is %d.\n",
                getppid(), getpid());
            exit(0);
        }
        sleep(2);
        printf("Child PID is %d. Parent's PID is %d.\n", 
            getpid(), getppid());      
    } 
    else {
        sleep(3);
        printf("Parent PID is %d.\n", getpid());
    }
return (0);
}
```

**This is my current output:**

Second Grandchild. Parent's PID is 11022. Grandparent's PID is 11024.

First Grandchild. Parent's PID is 11022. Grandparent's PID is 11023.

Child PID is 11022. Parent's PID is 11021.

Parent PID is 11021.

**When this is the desired output:**

Second Grandchild. Parent's PID is 11022. Grandparent's PID is 11021.

First Grandchild. Parent's PID is 11022. Grandparent's PID is 11021.

Child PID is 11022. Parent's PID is 11021.

Parent PID is 11021.

**How do I go about saving the Parent PID for the grandchildren to use?**

Comment: If you save the parent (the original starting process) PID before forking anything, all the children and grandchildren will be able to use that variable.

Comment: Stylistic notes: return is not a function, so don't use parentheses; it's $CURRENTYEAR, you don't have to declare variables at the top of the function; avoid complex mixtures of assignments and conditionals; use separate functions to make your code much more readable. This will help you actually get to all 10 processes that you need.

Comment: @sj95126 How do I go about making sure that I save the parent PID for the grandchildren? It saves for the children, but not the grandchildren and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Gabriella: just put ```pid_t parent_pid = getpid();``` at the beginning before the first ```fork()``` and then the children and grandchildren can use it. Where you're printing "Grandparent's PID" you're actually printing the grandchild's pid (```getpid()```).

Comment: @sj95126 Thank you so much! First time coding in C and this has all been really confusing to me. That was it!